# Android: Deleting a row from SQLite table and updating a ListView

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android development and have come across a problem with deleting a row in a SQLite table that I have not been able to find a solution to. When I try to delete a row nothing is happening.

In my activity, called 'MainActivity,' I am using a context menu to call a method to delete an item from the list. This portion of code is as follows:

```
case R.id.delete_program:
DBAdapter adap = new DBAdapter(this);
adap.open();
long pass = (long) (position + 1);
adap.removeFromCurrent(pass);
adap.close();   

Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    public void run(){                      
        refreshCurrent(getApplicationContext());
    }
};
runOnUiThread(run);
proAdapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
   return true;
```

In 'DBAdapter' the method removeFromCurrent():

```
public boolean removeFromCurrent(long cp_id) {

    return this.dB.delete(PROGRAMS_TABLE, CP_ID + '=' + cp_id, null) > 0;
}
```

In 'MainActivity' the method refreshCurrent():

```
public static void refreshCurrent(Context context) {        
    CURRENT.clear();
    DBAdapter adap = new DBAdapter(context);
    adap.open();        
    ArrayList<Program> temp = adap.getCurrentPrograms();
    for(Program item : temp) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Item added: " + item.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        CURRENT.add(item);
    }
    adap.close();       
}
```

I'm using the toast to check if the table has changed but the display has not.
From 'DBAdapter' the method getCurrentPrograms():

```
public ArrayList<Program> getCurrentPrograms() { 
    ArrayList<Program> list = new ArrayList<Program>();

    Cursor cursor =
            this.dB.query(PROGRAMS_TABLE, new String[] {
                    CP_ID, CP_NAME, ACTUAL_DAY, D_ID, CP_CYCLE, CP_DAY_ONE }, 
                    null, null, null, null, null);

    int rows = cursor.getCount();

    if(cursor != null) 
        cursor.moveToFirst();       

    for(int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        list.add(new Program(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CP_NAME)), 
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ACTUAL_DAY)), 
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CP_DAY_ONE)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CP_CYCLE))));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }                   
    return list;
}
```

The ArrayList 'CURRENT' is the list used to populate the ListView. My thinking was that I would be able to delete a row from the table and then repopulate this list as well as the ListView. I was also curious as to what happened to a SQLite table once a row is removed; do the other rows move up a position, or do they stay in the same place?

I am still very new to this so any help about my problem or tips for the rest of my code would be much appreciated. Let me know what else I'm doing wrong with my programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `SQLiteOpenHelper` you should be getting a `SQLiteDatabase` object and then using a transaction, if you don't set it as successful then nothing will happen

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();
//Do stuff
db.setTrasactionSuccessfull();
db.endTransaction();
```

Also I think when you pass null into the where clause the where doesn't matter.

You should have something like `db.delete("tbl", "id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});`

Comment: I figured out what was wrong with my code; I didn't have a correct understanding of how auto increment worked. I was under the impression that by removing a row, all rows above would be decremented by one. This led me to believe that I would be able to have an array list that would correspond to the row ids in my table. Do you know how my original belief may be achieved?

Comment: It would be against the principles of databases to do that, a row id is meant to be unique for the entire life of that table, why not populate the data into some kind of HashMap or Dictionary type thing?